# Hyperlink for Grid View cells in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

"How can I do hyperlink in JavaScript function for Grid view cell to point another function in the same script.
currently I'm trying to do this:

```
var gri = document.getElementById('<%= GridView2.ClientID %>');
var rows = gri.getElementsByTagName('tr');
for (var j = 0; j < rows.length; ++j) {
    var cells = rows[j].getElementByTagName("td"); 
    if (cells.length > 0) {
        cells[0].innerText = serviceWindowdate.link("divcolapse(date)");
    }
}
```

It is not giving me proper output in page.

Comment: `serviceWindowdate.link("divcolapse(date)")`? What's that?

Comment: serviceWindowdate is variable, value in this variable i need to show in grid view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
if (cells.length > 0) {
    cells[0].innerHtml = "<a href='javascript://yourFunction();'>Link text</a>";
}
```

Comment: This is not working, it reads the anchor tag, while showing output it won't come.  anyway thank you for ur suggestion.

Comment: need to change 'innerHtml' to 'innerHTML'  case sensitive. works fine now thank you Akbari